# foldl / foldr query

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm a beginner at Haskell, and even after reading several explanations of foldr/foldl, I can't understand why I'm getting different results below. What is the explanation?

```
Prelude> foldl (\_ -> (+1)) 0 [1,2,3]
4
Prelude> foldr (\_ -> (+1)) 0 [1,2,3]
3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! There is no need to add a signature, since there will appear a box with your name in it at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `foldl` case, the lambda is being passed the accumulator as the first argument, and the list element as the second.  In the `foldr` case, the lambda is being passed the list element as the first argument, and the accumulator as the second.

Your lambda ignores the first argument, and adds 1 to the second, so in the `foldl` case you are adding 1 to the last element, and in the `foldr` case, you are counting the number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 8):

That's because the order of the arguments is flipped in `foldl`. Compare their type signatures:

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

So you see, in your code using `foldl`, you repeatly increment the accumulator, ignoring the list. But in the code with `foldr`, you don't even touch the accumulator, but just increment the element of the list. As the last element is `3`, the result is `3 + 1 = 4`.

You could see your misstake more easy, if you'd use a list of characters aka string instead:

```
ghci> foldr (\_ -> (+1)) 0 ['a','b','c']
3
ghci> foldl (\_ -> (+1)) 0 ['a','b','c']

:1:20:
    No instance for (Num Char)
      arising from the literal `0'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Char)
    In the second argument of `foldl', namely `0'
    In the expression: foldl (\ _ -> (+ 1)) 0 ['a', 'b', 'c']
    In an equation for `it':
        it = foldl (\ _ -> (+ 1)) 0 ['a', 'b', 'c']
ghci>
```

Answer (score 6):

In `foldl f`, the accumulator is the left argument to `f`, which you are ignoring, therefore returning `1 +` the last element. With `foldr`, the accumulator is the right argument, so you're increasing the accumulator by 1 for every item, effectively giving the length of the list.

```
f x y = y + 1

foldl f 0 [1, 2, 3]
= f (f (f 0 1) 2) 3 
= f ignored 3
= 3 + 1
= 4

foldr f 0 [1, 2, 3]
= f 1 (f 2 (f 3 0)))
= f ignored (f ignored (f ignored 0)))
= ((((0 + 1) + 1) + 1)
= 3
```

Answer (score 6):

The difference is because of two things:

- You're discarding one input to the accumulating function and applying a constant function to the other.
- The order of arguments to the accumulating function are different between the two.

With the left fold, the accumulator is the argument you discard, so each time you're applying `(+1)` to the next item in the list and eventually return the last element plus one.

With the right fold, the accumulator is the argument you keep, so each time you're applying `(+1)` to the previous result, which is 0 to start with and gets incremented three times (for each item in the list).

It might be easier to see what's going on here if you use more obviously distinct input values:

```
Prelude> foldl (\_ -> (+1)) 100 [5,6,7]
8
Prelude> foldr (\_ -> (+1)) 100 [5,6,7]
103
```

Again, "last argument plus one" and "length of list plus initial value".

Answer (score 5):

Removing the currying and point free style may help. Your two expressions are equivilent to:

```
foldl (\acc x ->   x + 1) 0 [1,2,3]
foldr (\x acc -> acc + 1) 0 [1,2,3]
```

When viewed as such the results should appear more obvious