# Haskell foldr and foldl

Tags: haskell

The code below is used to generate the intersection of two lists:

```
unionSet :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
unionSet a b = foldl (\acc x -> if elem x acc then acc else acc ++ [x]) a b
```

Why does the `foldl` function work but when I use `foldr` it generates errors?

Comment: 1. You cannot "intersect two lists". You can intersect sets. Your code mentions "union", not "intersect". You can use lists to represent sets. But you should not, most of the time. 2. "code does not work" - be more specific. Syntax error? Type error? Semantics error (you get a result, but it is wrong)? In the latter case, also include the specification (that says what is right).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [foldl / foldr query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050306/foldl-foldr-query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foldr` has the type

```
(a -> b -> b) -> [a] -> b -> b
```

while `foldl` has the type

```
(b -> a -> b) -> [a] -> b -> b
```

Note the order of the two parameters.

```
(\x acc -> ...
```

would fix the error.

Comment: This is done so make it more apparent what order the operator is applied in.